# Systemd - Python script - Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, python

Hi everyone the situation is the following:
I am connetected to an ubuntu-based EC2 machine of AWS ( and I am currently working on Ubuntu 18.04).
I can manage files inside the machine and run scripts from terminal but I want the machine to run a script even when I am not connected. So I thought about a service.

Using systemd I located this file on /lib/systemd/system :

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Service
After=network.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service 

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3  /home/ubuntu/GreenHouse/Catalog/Catalog_REST.py
StandardInput=tty-force 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I started the service,ut when I check the status:

```
 sudo systemctl status CATALOG_REST-py.service
```

I receive this error:

```
● CATALOG_REST-py.service - Test Service    
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/CATALOG_REST-py.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)    
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-08-22 16:54:13 UTC; 1s ago   
Process: 23968 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/GreenHouse/Catalog/Catalog_REST.py (code=exited,
status=1/FAILURE)  
Main PID: 23968 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 22 16:54:13 ip-172-31-13-245 systemd[1]: Started Test Service. 
Aug 22 16:54:13 ip-172-31-13-245 systemd[1]: CATALOG_REST-py.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAIL 
Aug 22 16:54:13 ip-172-31-13-245 systemd[1]: CATALOG_REST-py.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I want to say that if I run in terminal `python3 /home/GreenHouse/Catalog/Catalog_REST.py` , it works.

Do you know some ways to obtain a **better explanation of the error**?

Comment: An exit code of 1 in python probably means someplace in your code you have an intentional exit. Check your code. Maybe have it generate output when it exits.

Comment: It actually works when I launch it from terminal without using systemd

Answer (score -2):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `systemd` startup scripts aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. `systemd` startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: This does not answer the question ("Do you know some ways to obtain a better explanation of the error?").

Comment: I have not understood... What I have to look for running echos?